How i connect signalR hub server that deployed in ECS
I have an issue as described below:
I have a SignalR hub deployed on ECS 1. When using ECS 2 to connect to ECS 1, everything works fine, and SignalR runs okay.
However, when I run the app using the .exe file on EC2 (which is used for ECS 2), I cannot connect to the SignalR hub deployed on ECS 1. It gives an error:
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[41]
      Starting HubConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[1]
      Starting HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[8]
      Establishing connection with server at 'http://10.x.x.x:8080/traiHub'.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.LoggingHttpMessageHandler[2]
      Unsuccessful HTTP response 503 return from POST 'http://10.x.x.x:8080/traiHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1'.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[10]
      Failed to start connection. Error getting negotiation response from 'http://10.x.x.x:8080/traiHub'.
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Service Unavailable).
         at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[5]
      Skipping dispose, connection is already disposed.
fail: Common.Hub.TraiHubClient[0]
      Failed to start the hub connection
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Service Unavailable).
         at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Common.Hub.TraiHubClient.StartHubConnectionAsync() in C:\Users\c900961\Desktop\torpod\src\Common\Hub\TraiHubClient.cs:line 60
fail: Common.Hub.TraiHubClient[0]
      Failed to start the hub connection
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Service Unavailable).
         at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Common.Hub.TraiHubClient.StartHubConnectionAsync() in C:\Users\c900961\Desktop\torpod\src\Common\Hub\TraiHubClient.cs:line 60
         at Common.Hub.TraiHubClient..ctor(String hubUrl, String methodName, ILogger`1 logger) in C:\Users\c900961\Desktop\torpod\src\Common\Hub\TraiHubClient.cs:line 48

my debug client log
please help me
I've tried opening CORS on the SignalR hub server, but nothing has changed.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
            builder
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true) // Allow any origin
                .AllowAnyHeader()              // Allow any header
                .AllowAnyMethod()              // Allow any HTTP method
                .AllowCredentials();           // Allow credentials (cookies, authorization headers)
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();

------2024/04/22 Update----
i have add server side logging
        builder.Logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR", LogLevel.Debug);
    builder.Logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections", LogLevel.Debug);
    builder.Host.UseNLog();
    builder.Services.AddSignalR();
    var app = builder.Build();

this log in cloudwatch
2024-04-22T11:24:15.178+09:00   [2024-04-22 11:24:15.1683] [INFO] [Lifetime] Now listening on: http://[::]:80
2024-04-22T11:24:15.179+09:00   [2024-04-22 11:24:15.1795] [INFO] [Lifetime] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2024-04-22T11:24:15.179+09:00   [2024-04-22 11:24:15.1795] [INFO] [Lifetime] Hosting environment: Production
2024-04-22T11:24:15.179+09:00   [2024-04-22 11:24:15.1795] [INFO] [Lifetime] Content root path: C:\app\
2024-04-22T11:24:15.517+09:00   [2024-04-22 11:24:15.5168] [WARN] [HttpsRedirectionMiddleware] Failed to determine the https port for redirect.

Looks like it's not working yet ?
My TraiHubClient.cs
public TraiHubClient(string hubUrl, string methodName, ILogger<TraiHubClient> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _hubUrl = hubUrl;
            _methodName = methodName;
            Console.WriteLine("Connect : {url}", _hubUrl);
            Console.WriteLine("methodName : {_methodName}", _methodName);

            _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(_hubUrl, HttpTransportType.WebSockets | HttpTransportType.LongPolling)
                .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();

            // Call a separate async method to start the connection asynchronously
            StartHubConnectionAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private async Task StartHubConnectionAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
                _logger.LogInformation("Hub connection started successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to start the hub connection");
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(TrainRadioReceiveModel trainInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Connected : {url}", _hubUrl);
                _logger.LogInformation(
                    "Received data info: {arg}",
                    JsonSerializer.Serialize(trainInfo)
                );
                await _hubConnection.InvokeAsync(_methodName, trainInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Invoke hub error");
                throw;
            }
        }


Try to use https://xxxx.elb.amazonaws.com/traiHub , instead of http://10.x.x.x:8080/traiHub.

Could you try to disable the firewall in your ESC1 a few mins for testing, then enable it again. I just want to identify whether the issue related to the security settings or not?

@JasonPan
I've added logs and can see them in CloudWatch as follows:
[2024-04-22 13:10:39.3736] [INFO] [TrainRadioEventListener] TrainRadioEventListener started listening on http://xxxx.elb.amazonaws.com/traiHub.
My log connection in EC2:
info: Common.Hub.TraiHubClient[0]
Connect : http://xxxx.elb.amazonaws.com/traiHub.
info: Common.Hub.TraiHubClient[0]
methodName : UpdateTraiInfo
But it's still not working.

@JasonPan I've tried turning it off and on firewall on hub server multiple times, but it's still the same :(

Hello user24480462, we have tried many ways, right ? According to my experience, please try to use a random port, something like 44335, and try again.

Dear user24480462, if it still not working, my next plan is creating a html page(chat feature) in your asp.net core project, the difference is in your side you are using .net library, I want to open the chat page in your ECS2 browser, then check if it works or not.

@JasonPan Thank you for your help. I will follow your advice and report the results to you soon

@JasonPan I've figured out the reason. When creating the EC2 instance, the IT department of my company added an HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variable to the EC2 environment variables. When I added the URL of the load balancer to the NO_PROXY environment variable, the system started working.
Thank you very much for your help, and I hope you have a wonderful workday!
